# Why this function invocation return a string and not a number

Tags: javascript

I want to store a function and its arguments in an object and invoke it via this object, as follows:

```js
var fn = function(x, y) {
  return x + y
};
var obj = {
  'args': [2, 3],
  'func': fn
};
console.log(obj.func(obj['args']));
```

Why does this code return a string `"2,3undefined"`? It's not even '23' if it receives the arguments as strings and `+` concats them. How do I make it return 5 as expected? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Because the first argument you pass is the array `[2,3]`, the second is undefined since you don't pass anything to it. The `+` operator is overloaded, it does addition, concatenation or type conversion to Number depending on the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array as a single parameter to the function

```
var fn = function(x,y) {return x + y };
```

And your call looks like `fn([2, 3])`

So in runtime the `x` equals to the array, and `y` equals to `undefined`. You passed nothing.

```
[2, 3] + undefined
```

is evaluated into a string, since the scalar value of `[2, 3]` is `2,3`. And `string + undefined` expression casts the second operand to string as well, hence `2,3undefined`.

To "fix" it - use the `Function.prototype.apply`:

```
fn.apply(null, [2, 3])
```

or in your case

```
console.log(obj.func.apply(null, obj['args']));
```

References:

- [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
- [The Addition Operator - Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

Answer (score 3):

Try using [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call the function instead:

```
var fn = function(x,y) {return x + y };
var obj = { 'args': [2, 3], 'func' : fn};
console.log(obj.func.apply(obj, obj['args']));
```

In your example, what you're actually doing is passing the entire array as the 'x' argument and an undefined y value.  Apply will call the function with the supplied array as the arguments.

Comment: The OP can also use [*ECMAScript 2015 spread syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) in the call: `obj.func(...obj['args'])`. ;-)